# How to sum running total for Quantity column per item and get only the day which the stock became Zero in the total

Tags: sql

```
  Posting Date  Item No_    Quantity    TOTAL   DAYS
  30/06/2016    100920        20         20  
  03/07/2016    100920        -3         17  
  04/07/2016    100920        -2         15  
  05/07/2016    100920        -3         12  
  06/07/2016    100920        -1         11  
  07/07/2016    100920        -1         10  
  08/07/2016    100920        -1          9  
  09/07/2016    100920        -4          5  
  10/07/2016    100920        -1          4  
  11/07/2016    100920        -1          3  
  13/07/2016    100920        -1          2  
  17/07/2016    100920        -2          0     4
  21/07/2016    100920        40         40  
  21/07/2016    100921        40         40  
  22/07/2016    100921       -4          36  
  23/07/2016    100921       -3          33  
  25/07/2016    100921       -3          30  
  26/07/2016    100921       -2          28  
  27/07/2016    100921       -2          26  
  29/07/2016    100921       -3          23  
  30/07/2016    100921       -5          18  
  31/07/2016    100921       -4          14  
  01/08/2016    100921      -10           4  
  02/08/2016    100921       -3           1  
  06/08/2016    100921       -1           0     1
  07/08/2016    100921       20          20
```

I need to sum the running total for quantity column by item and return only the days in which the stock has become zero in the total column. I also need to get the time difference between the date that it became zero and the next day we received an order

I need the output to be:

```
  Posting Date  Item No_    TOTAL   DAYS
   17/07/2016   100920        0      4
   06/08/2016   100921        0      1
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Where do you get the date that the last order came through? We need information to compare it to "the next day we received an order"

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to calculate the `total` and `days` columns, although your question isn't clear on this.  If so:

```
select t.*, (next_posting_date - posting_date) as days
from (select t.*,
             sum(quantity) over (partition by item_no order by posting_date) as total,
             lead(posting_date) over (partition by item_no order by posting_date) as next_posting_date
      from t
     ) t
where total = 0;
```

Date functions are notoriously database-dependent, so the exact syntax for `days` may depend on your database.